# How to make a unicode triangle wider

Tags: css

I'm using a pseudo-element of content to make a triangle that I want floating outside the upper

Setup of problem: Get the blue triangle on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y2bfuch/) to be wider (but keep its height)

```
.bluebox { margin-top: 50px; background: blue; min-width: 300px; min-height: 200px; position: relative;}
    .bluebox:after { content: "\25B2"; color: blue; position: absolute; font-size: 2em; top: -0.8em; left: 5%;}
```

What attribute to I need to tweak in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If supporting IE8 and below is not a concern, you could apply `scaleX()` transform function with to the pseudo-element.

For instance (*Vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity*):

```
.bluebox:after {
    /* other declarations... */
    content: "\25B2";
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
}
```

Online Example:

```css
.bluebox {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: blue;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.bluebox:after {
     content: "\25B2";
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2em;
    top: -0.8em; left: 5%;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1.5);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1.5);
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebox"></div>
```